# How to stop input in programming c language

Tags: c

Im trying to get it to stop but im not quite sure how to do that. Im just starting to learn it. I want it to stop when I type -99.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

this is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
int main(void)
{
    int hot=0, pleasant=0, cold=0;
    int sum=0, i, temp;
    double average;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter temperature %d> (-99 to stop)",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        sum +=temp;

         if(temp >= 85)
        {
            ++hot;
        }

        else if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 84)
        {
            ++pleasant;
        }

        else
        {
            ++cold;
        }
    }
    average = (double) sum/SIZE;

    printf("The Collection of hot days is %d\n",hot);
    printf("The Collection of pleasant days is %d\n",pleasant);
    printf("The Collection of cold days is %d\n",cold);
    printf("The Average temperature is %.2f\n",average);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `if( temp == -99 ) break;`

Comment: See [`break`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break).

Comment: Also replace this `for` loop with an infinite loop.

Comment: And you probably need a counter to count how many temps were *actually* entered, or you could use `hot+pleasant+cold`.

Comment: You should divide by the number of temperatures entered, which won't be the same as `SIZE` if they end it early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to break out of the loop:

```
if (temp == -99)
  break;
```

But there are several other issues with your code, such as the averaging calculation will be wrong if you exit early. Here is a corrected version that also makes use of the other loop control word `continue`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_len;
    int hot=0, pleasant=0, cold=0;
    int sum=0, i=0, temp;
    double average;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter temperature %d> (-99 to stop)",i);

        buffer = NULL;
        getline(&buffer, &buffer_len, stdin);
        if (buffer_len == 0 || sscanf(buffer, "%d\n",&temp) != 1)
        {
            if (buffer)
              free(buffer);
            printf("Invalid\n");
            continue;
        }

        free(buffer);

        if(temp == -99)
          break;

        sum +=temp;
        ++i;

        if(temp >= 85)
        {
            ++hot;
            continue;
        }

        if(temp >= 60)
        {
            ++pleasant;
            continue;
        }

        ++cold;
    }

    if (i == 0)
    {
      printf("No temperatures entered\n");
      return -1;
    }

    average = (double)sum / i;

    printf("The Collection of hot days is %d\n",hot);
    printf("The Collection of pleasant days is %d\n",pleasant);
    printf("The Collection of cold days is %d\n",cold);
    printf("The Average temperature is %.2f\n",average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `i` is initialized to `1`?

Comment: I would get rid of it anyway. You can just sum `hot`, `cold` and `pleasant`.

Comment: Perhaps so, but checking for divide by zero before performing the actual divide then would require duplicated code.

Comment: Interesting use of `continue;`.  Not a coding style I would recommend, but its your code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but the OP uses it in the user prompt

Comment: I would take the `continue` thing as didactic example of usage. Otherwise it is ugly :)

Comment: By using continue we avoid the need for nested else statements, which in this example is perhaps over usage, but it is handy when dealing with large if/else/if/else blocks.

Comment: I tried this and for me it automatically assumes there is no temperature inputted and instantly stops?

Comment: @svr07madden Works fine for me, check your code, check you compiled it correctly. The loop is infinite, it will only stop if you enter -99;

Comment: I copied it exactly as you had it in that post, and it instantly stopped.

Comment: nevermind, lol. I guess i did indeed copy it wrong. Thanks so much!!

Comment: No worries. I just updated the answer to deal properly with invalid input by using `getline` and `sscanf` rather then `scanf`. If this has resovled the problem please do not forget to mark this question as answered.